# How to set different data source for different combo box?

Tags: swift, combobox, datasource

I have 3 arrays and 3 comboboxes how do I set the the 3 different arrays as data sources for the 3 different comboboxes
I know to set the data source for 1 combo box we need to do this

```
class class1: NSViewController, NSComboBoxDataSource {
@IBOutlet weak var combobox1: NSComboBox!
@IBOutlet weak var combobox2: NSComboBox!
@IBOutlet weak var combobox3: NSComboBox!

var array1 = ["1", "2", "3"]
var array2 = ["4", "5", "6"]
car array3 = ["7", "8", "9"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    combobox1.usesDataSource = true
    combobox1.dataSource = self
    
    combobox2.usesDataSource = true
    combobox2.dataSource = self
    
    combobox3.usesDataSource = true
    combobox3.dataSource = self
}

    func numberOfItems(in comboBox: NSComboBox) -> Int {
    return array1.count
}

func comboBox(_ comboBox: NSComboBox, objectValueForItemAt index: Int) -> Any? {
    return array1[index]
} }
```

I know this will set the values of array1 to combobox1 but how do I set array2 to combobox2 and array 3 to combobox 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
func comboBox(_ comboBox: NSComboBox, objectValueForItemAt index: Int) -> Any? 
{
   if comboBox == comboBox1 { return array1[index] }
   else if comboBox == comboBox2 { return array2[index] }
   else if comboBox == comboBox3 { return array3[index] }
   return nil
}
```

Comment: Do i need to do the same in `numberOfItems`. If the 3 arrays contain different amounts of data?

Comment: Yes, you need to do the same when provide number of items